# Fullcalendar view columnFormat being igored

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm having a challenge formatting the column headings for the following fullcalendar view.

```
 views: {
        timeline7Days: {
            columnFormat: 'ddd D/M',
            type: 'timelineWeek',
            slotDuration: '24:00',
            duration: { days: 7 },
            buttonText: 'resource week',
            resourceEditable: false

    },
```

Basically, it ignores the column format of 'ddd D/M' and displays each column with the title of 'Mo 16' instead of 'Mon 1/16'.  Any ideas?

[click here for jsbin](http://jsbin.com/diladozeco/2/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

There is definately something wrong with columnFormat for custom view. You could try such trick:

```
viewRender: function( view, element ) {
      if (view.name == 'timeline7Days') {
     $("th[data-date]").each(function(){
       $(this).find('span').text(moment($(this).data().date).format('ddd M/D'));
    });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your example didn't exactly work, but it helped put me on the right track.

I ended up using the following code (replaced 'span' with 'a'.
'code'

```
if ((view.name == 'timeline7Days') || (view.name = 'timelineMonth'))
            {
                $("th[data-date]").each(function()
                {
                    $(this).find('a').text(moment($(this).data().date).format('ddd M/D'))
                });
            }
```